# Is modified UTF-8 handling in JNI::NewStringUTF changed in recent Android versions?

Tags: java, android, utf-8, java-native-interface

In earlier Android versions, `JNI:NewStringUTF` used to give an error when passed a valid UTF-8 string with 4 bytes encoding:

> input is not valid Modified UTF-8

It was due to the fact that JNI/Java uses modified UTF-8. There are plenty of posts here highlighting the issue.

However, I accidentally discovered that in recent Android versions, `NewStringUTF` accepts the same string which was causing a problem earlier. I tested on Android 31. I tried multiple strings and all of them worked. Below is a hex dump of one such string:

```
000000: e2 98 ba f0 9f 98 8a f0 9f 98 80 f0 9f 98 81 f0   ................
000010: 9f 98 82 f0 9f 98 83 f0 9f 98 84 f0 9f 98 af f0   ................
000020: 9f 98 89 f0 9f 98 88 f0 9f 98 87                  ...........
```

Has something changed?

Comment: _when_ did you last test this? I see a [commit from 2021](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/art/+/edc005e396947fb4fa681c4a0be7beba66354239) that says 4-byte UTF-8 sequences were already accepted "for historical reasons".

Comment: At least going back to 2015 this function should have accepted 4-byte UTF-8. What Android versions can you get this to fail on?

Comment: @Botje, thanks a ton. I didn't know about this commit, very helpful. We have historic code which supports API 16 onward and goes back to 2015. So it is safe to remove those checks now?

Comment: According to [this site](https://apilevels.com/) the first release after 2015 is Android 7.0 Nougat (API level 24), with a cumulative reach of 96.8%. Also note that Google dropped support for play services below API level 21.

Comment: thanks @Botje. I agree, we should be upgrading minimum version though we still have users using api level 19

Answer (score -1):

At least since 2015, the NewStringUTF function has supported 4-byte UTF-8 inputs. It is safe to assume that this works for devices with Android 7.0 and above.

Comment: Thanks, I am accepting your answer. However, the Android 7 implementation is not complete. While it accepts 4 bytes encoding, it incorrectly uses modified utf-8 encoding for termination (0xc0 0x80) when sending string from java to jni. Android 10 (API level 29) onward, both way works fine. I still need to check API level 26-28.

Comment: Why is that "incorrect"? That is actually the raison d'etre of modified UTF-8 : it prevents nul bytes from showing up in strings. Or maybe I misunderstood the meaning of "termination"...

Comment: it is incorrect because it is a mix up in Andorid 7. When sending from Java to JNI, the string is converted from modified utf-8 to utf-8 but the 0xc0 0x80 termination is left as it is. In later versions, it is fixed and has correct 0 termination.

Comment: I don't think you can rely on the `char *` coming from `GetStringUTFChars` having any nul-termination. You are supposed to use `GetStringUTFLength` and read exactly that amount of bytes from the pointer.

Comment: Although in practice it has been NUL-terminated since 2011. Unless you are talking about a NUL byte embedded in a Java string? I don't get your comment, sorry.